# Installing the Correct Ruby / rbenz for new Macbook Air (M1) for Appacademy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I am starting the appacademy open course and am trying to get Ruby set up the way they want. I've followed their instructions installing rbenz. I installed rbenz 2.7.2 because i hear this is compatible with the new M1 chips. Everything seems to have worked. However, when I check the ruby version (ruby -v) I run into a repeating error:

````
/Users/raylang/.rbenv/shims/ruby: line 3: =: command not found
/Users/raylang/.rbenv/shims/ruby: line 3: =: command not found
/Users/raylang/.rbenv/shims/ruby: line 3: =: command not found```



It's weird because it tells me that I have installed it already:

```Installed openssl-1.1.1k to /Users/raylang/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2

Downloading ruby-2.7.2.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.2.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.7.2...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew
Installed ruby-2.7.2 to /Users/raylang/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2```


Any ideas anyone?
````

Answer (score 0):

I guess you installed rbenv with homebrew

Did you update your .bashrc or .zshrc?

if not yet, add following

```
# rbenv
export PATH="~/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="~/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

then restart terminal.

After that set global ruby version.

```
rbenv global x.x.x # 2.7.2 etc.
```

Then you can use `ruby -v`

for more information: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation

Comment: I followed your instructions and the repeating errors have gone away and i am now left with:

```/Users/raylang/.rbenv/shims/ruby: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable```

still some troubleshooting to do. But thank you